# How do I validate update based on selected values in a key with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, parameters, updating

I want to implement a conditional update method on a specific set of values for a key.

I want to allow updates only if the original list.permissions values (set on create) equal either "public", "viewable, or "editable".  If the list.permissions value for a record does not equal one of those three acceptable values, updating the record is denied (locked).

I tried modifying the strong params in a private method in the controller file:

```
def list_params_validated
     params.require(:list).permit(:title, permissions: ["public",  "viewable", "editable"])
end
```

and then calling  that in my `update` method in the same controller:

```
def update
  list = List.find(params[:id])
  if list.update(list_params_validated)

    render json: list

  else
    render json: { errors: list.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

no luck with this, any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Why are you doing so?We can simply use validate_inclusion_of 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of

Comment: Hi there.  I'm not sure that helps because creating the record allows for a multitude of different values for that permissions key.  It's only updating a preexisting record that I want to allow for, dependent solely on the existence of either  of those three values in that permissions key.

Comment: Please update your question. It doesn't includes `locked` permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an custom validation on your `List` model as following and call simple `update` in controller.

`self.permissions` value should be `string` like `"public"` or  `"viewable"` or `"editable"`.

```
validate :validate_editable, :validate_permissions:on => :update


def editable?
   self.permissions != "locked"
end

private

def validate_editable
   errors.add(:base, "Not Ediable!") unless  editable?
end

def validate_permissions
   unless ["public",  "viewable", "editable"].include?(self.permissions)
      errors.add(:base, "Permission denied!")
   end 
end
```

Comment: hi thanks, this looks great however I ran a test on a record with a list value of "locked" (not one of the three permissible values for updating).  I then used curl in terminal to successfully update the permission value to "public" (one of the allowed permission values).  Is there anything we can do to lock it down, even if we try to change it to one of the permissible values?

Comment: Answer has been edited to check `if locked`, wish this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this on your controller

```
def list_params_validated
     params.require(:list).permit(:title, :permissions)
end
```

and in your model simply add this

```
validates_inclusion_of :permissions, in: %w(public viewable editable), :on => :update, :message => "value %s is invalid!"
```

## EDIT 1

To prevent updating the record, You should add before_update callback in your model as

```
  before_update :locked?

def locked?
    return false if YourModel.find(id).persmissions == 'locked'
    true
end
```

Comment: thank you!  This is very close.  However, as a test, I went to a list with a value that wasnt one of the permissible three values, then did an update to one of the three values and was allowed.  Is there anything I can add to lock down editing if its only one of those three values to start?

Comment: Sorry
but I didn't get you?
If you don't mind can you please elaborate

Comment: sure!  OK, say I have a record with permissions value set to "locked" (not "public", "viewable", or "editable").  I should not be allowed to edit anything in this record, but even with the validation you recommended above, I can change the permissions value to "public".

I cannot change it to anything else but "public", "editable" or "viewable", but ideally I shouldn't be able to change it to anything since those weren't the set permissions value for the record on create.

Comment: ok @dpg5000 looks like your question did not speak enough to make us understand your requirements. please update your question with the term `locked` as well